# 18.04 LTS vs 20.04.3 LTS: Stretchable Desktop Icons (Photos on the Desktop)

Tags: 20.04, desktop-icons, thumbnails

I lasted a year to upgrade ubuntu from 18.04 LTS to 20.04.3 LTS, this because upgrading there was a loss of functionality. In fact, before I had photos on the desktop made with the thumbnails or icons stretched of the .jpg images, or more of the .pdf images.
Now this is not more possible!
How to solve it?